# Help with a proof of Sharp's Steps in commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand the following part of this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Steps_in_Commutative_Algebra.html?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&redir_esc=y)

[image]

I couldn't prove that $aR=\Pi_{i=1}^sRp^{t_i}_i$.

**$\subset$ part:**

$x\in aR\implies x=ar_1\implies x=up_1^{t_1}...p_s^{t_s}r_1\implies x=(ur_1)p_1^{t_1}...p_s^{t_s}, r_1\in R$, since $R$ is commutative, then $x=(ur_1p_1^{t_1})(1p_2^{t_2})...(1p_s^{t_s}x) \in \Pi_{i=1}^sRp^{t_i}_i$

I need help with the converse.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @YACP what is RHS?

Comment: There is a problem, how can I find the unit $u$ to get an element of $aR$?

Comment: $x\in\Pi_{i=1}^sRp^{t_i}_i$ then $x=r\Pi_{i=1}^sp^{t_i}_i$ so $x=(u^{-1}r)u\Pi_{i=1}^sp^{t_i}_i=(u^{-1}r)a\in Ra$.

Comment: @YACP of course, so stupid question, thank you very much, I'm very grateful for your help.